# What situation does the Fool refer to at the start of Fools' Errand?

Tags: realm-of-the-elderlings

In the book Fool's errand, The Fool refers to a situation (during his first meeting with Fitz) in which he felt Fitz's presence with him.

> He describes a situation in which he was undergoing one of his fevers, and expected somebody to assault (and kill) him. Fitz explains he stopped the person.

What time and person did the Fool refer to?

Answer (score 4):

This takes place in *Ship of Destiny*, book three of *The Liveship Traders;* so, don't read the answer if you haven't read the *Liveship* books.

> Lavoy, first mate of *The Paragon* reports to Brashen Trell that "The carpenter is unconscious on the forward deck". When Trell asked what happened, Lavoy says, Damn me if I know. I just found her there and thought you'd like to know." We later find out in *Fool's Errand* that Lavoy had intended to hurt Amber, but that Fitz had *repelled* at him.